# Apache, Mod_security, and Wordpress, can't remove by rule ID

Tags: wordpress, apache, lamp, mod-security

I have been look around trying to get this working right for a while now, and finally bit the bullet and posted here.

I've got a LAMP stack with ModSecurity using the OWASP core rule set (v 2.2.5) and just installed Wordpress. I expected conflicts with ModSecurity, but I haven't been able to ignore or work aroudn the only error I've encountered so far.

The Apache error.log file and the modsec_audit.log both list the same error:

> ModSecurity: Rule 7f5d9a449228 [id "950901"][file "/etc/modsecurity/owasp-crs/activated_rules/modsecurity_crs_41_sql_injection_attacks.conf"][line "77"] - Execution error - PCRE limits exceeded (-8): (null).`

I've tried creating a new .conf file where the crs conf files are located containing

```
<LocationMatch .*>
  <IfModule mod_security2.c>
    SecRuleRemoveById 950901
  </IfModule>
</LocationMatch>
```

and even removed the `IfModule` statement and then `LocationMatch` statement when it didn't work.

Finally I resorted to commenting out lines 76 and 77 in the .conf file, and the error still appeared. This also had no effect.

Only changing `SecRuleEngine` to `Off` in `modsecurity.conf` finally let me access the page. Of course this defeats the purpose of `ModSec`.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this to your `php.ini` file (or included conf file):

```
pcre.backtrack_limit = 10000000
pcre.recursion_limit = 10000000
```

And then this to your `modsecurity.conf`:

```
SecPcreMatchLimit 150000
SecPcreMatchLimitRecursion 150000
```

This should allow for recursion without having to fully disable `mod_security`.

Comment: Thanks! That resolved all those errors, but of course I'm still getting a 403 when trying to access the same page. I've tried adding the new IDs into my whitelist.conf file, but it doesn't seem to have any effect. How can I get a 403 code referencing an ID code that (I'm 99% sure) I've eliminated?

Comment: 403 is somewhat generic... anything in your logs? If you haven't, enabling logging for mod_security is probably a good idea: http://www.modsecurity.org/documentation/modsecurity-apache/1.9.3/html-multipage/07-logging.html

Comment: turned out half my problem was a wordpress setting pointing to the wrong location to deposit files and not having permission to create the folder it needed to. thats 12 hours of my life i wont get back. but thanks for all your help, im going incorporate this anyway